# Is there a virtualization layer for the terminal to run 32-bit apps?

Tags: terminal, virtualization, 32-bit

I have a Windows app ([LROverhaul](https://github.com/LunaKampling/LROverhaul/)) that was formerly able to run in MacOS. It was a Windows .NET app that used Mono to run it. However, when Apple removed support for 32-bit apps, the old way (`mono --arch=32 linerider.exe`), it gives me a "Error: --arch=32 Failed to switch to 'mono32'." message. I think this is because MacOS 10.15 dropped support for 32-bit apps. Is there any "virtualization layer" that can run just in the terminal to enable the use of this app? I don't want to have to run a VM to use this.

Also, see my question [How do I run a .NET 4.8 app with Wine on M2 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247649/how-do-i-run-a-net-4-8-app-with-wine-on-m2-mac) on Stack Overflow about running the app on Mac.

Comment: Please don‘t send people offsite for parts of the question. If the information on SE is relevant for the question here, include the details directly.

Comment: Having said that: a VM of any kind (Mojave or Windows) is the way to go here.

Comment: There are 64-bit versions of Mono available from the [Mono web site](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) .

Comment: @MarcWilson yes I know that but I have to run this app in 32-bit mode (`mono --arch=32`). Is there any way to do that just in the terminal? I tried using Lima but it didn't have a GUI to run the app.

Comment: You can't run 32bit code in 10.15 or newer.

Comment: No way at all? Nothing? If not, what is the best VM solution for me to use? I have a M2 Mac with MacOS Sonoma.

Comment: Any will do :-) There are some questions with answers on AD on VMs already.